# Proving that $F$ is injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Problem: Let $f : A → B$ be an injective function. Define the function
$F : P(A) → P(B)$ by $F(A_0) = f(A_0)$ for all $A_0 ∈ P(A)$. Prove that $F$ is an
injective function.

Is the following attempt correct?

Proof. Let $a, a' \in f$ such that $f(a)=f(a') \Rightarrow a=a'$. Since for all $A_0 \in \mathcal{P} (A)$, $F(A_0) = f(A_0) $ and $a, a' \in \mathcal{P} (A)$, then $f(a) = F(a) = f(a') = F(a')$. Since $a, a' \in F$ and $F(a) = F(a')$, it follows that $a=a'$ and $F$ is injective.  QED

Comment: There are several problems with your attempt (starting with $a,a' \in f$ -- what does that mean?), but principally you've fallen prey to imprecise notation.  More properly stated, you should define $$F(A_0) = \{f(a_0) : a_0 \in A_0\}.$$  Use that definition instead, noting then that something like $f(a) = F(a) = f(a') = F(a')$ doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof doesn't really make sense. The crux of your argument is the claim that $f(a)=F(a)=f(a')=F(a')$ implies $a=a'$, but this seems to come out of nowhere at all. Note that the notation $f(A_0)$ for a subset $A_0\subseteq A$ denotes the **image** of the set $A_0$ under the function $f$, and in particular it does  not just mean the "output" of the function with "input" $A_0$ (which doesn't make sense because $A_0$ is not an element of the domain $A$).

What you need to show is $F(A_0)=F(A_1)$ for subsets $A_0,A_1\subseteq A$ implies $A_0=A_1$ as sets. You can do this by e.g. showing that the sets have the same elements. Let $a$ be an element of $A_0$ --- can you use the hypothesis to show that it is also an element of $A_1$? If so, you would have shown $A_0\subseteq A_1$, and the identical argument in reverse would show $A_1\subseteq A_0$, at which point you are done.

> If $a$ is an element of $A_0$, then $f(a)$ is an element of $F(A_0)$, and hence it is an element of $F(A_1)$. Thus $a=f^{-1}(f(a))$ belongs also to $A_1$, since this is the preimage of the set $F(A_1)$ by definition. Thus, $A_0\subseteq A_1$. The identical argument shows $A_1\subseteq A_0$, so that $A_0=A_1$ as desired.